# Prevent Postback in array of linkbutton is created at dynamically

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, event-handling

i have created Array of Linkbutton
and when user click on link button it will create an array of Radio Buttons
but it requires Postback all time so page load takes more time...
what is solution of it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asp.net Ajax update panel.
Put link buttons and panel/view (or what ever control you are using ) update panel.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am following a 100% but if you don't want to do a post back then your going to need to write some javascript(or use a framework like jquery) to generate radio buttons when the user clicks the link button(plus you probably don't want to use a link button then as it will try to always cause a postback or you will need to stop the post back from happening).